# C++ error at the last line of code

Tags: c++

I'm a begineer in C++ programming but I know the basics. 
I recently started writing a simple game. The program chooses a random number 
(1-100) and you have to guess it. There are 2 modes:

Normal - whenever you enter a number program tells you if it's bigger than the random or smaller.

hard - no clues, just pure luck.

Everything was running ok but when I added some fixes to the displayed text the program won't compile. I use CODE::BLOCKS.
Screenshot: http://scr.hu/81tw/m6cm0
I really apreciate your help.

Full code below:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int number_normal;
int number_hard;
int guess_normal;
int guess_hard;
int tries_normal=0;
int tries_hard=0;
int mode;
int main()
{


{
    cout<<"Choose your mode..."<<endl;
    cout<<"Normal (Press 1) or Hard (Press 2)"<<endl;
    cin>>mode;
    if(mode=1)
        cout<<"Normal mode chosen."<<endl;
            goto normal;
    if(mode=2)
        cout<<"Hard mode chosen!"<<endl;
            goto hard;
            return 0;
}
{

    hard:

        cout<<"I chose a random number in a range from 1 to 100, can you      guess it?"<<endl;
        srand(time(NULL));
        number_hard = rand()%100+1;

    while(guess_hard!=number_hard)

        tries_hard++;
        cout<<"Enter your guess!(Try "<<tries_hard<<"): ";
        cin>>guess_hard;

        if(guess_hard=number_normal)
            cout<<"Respect! You guessed it in "<<tries_hard<<" tries!"<<endl;
}
{

    normal:

        cout<<"I chose a random number from 1 to 100. I will give you some clues! Try to guess it."<<endl;
        srand(time(NULL));
        number_normal = rand()%100+1;

    while(guess_normal!=number_normal)

        tries_normal++;
        cout<<"Enter your guess!(Try "<<tries_normal<<"): ";
        cin>>guess_normal;

        if(guess_normal==number_normal)
            cout<<"Congrats! You're lucky. (Won in "<<tries_normal<<" tries!)"<<endl;

        if(guess_normal<number_normal)
            cout<<"Too low."<<endl;
        else if(guess_normal>number_normal)
            cout<<"That's too much!"<<endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about instead of a screenshot on a 3rd party site, you post your *acutal code* here, and provide the full error message?

Comment: Your code also has a number of problems. You should use `{}` braces to enclose the scope of `if` statements, `while` loops, etc. Also there are random `{}` scopes breaking up your code. Also there are a thousand better ways to handle flow control (e.g. functions) than using `goto` statements

Comment: Looks like you're coming from Python. Unfortunately your statement "I know the basics" seems to be a case of overconfidence.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` for the comparison statements right up top, and the rest of them.

Comment: Okay, but I still get an error at the very bottom line. You can see it on the screenshot.

Comment: No, a red rectangle is not a useful problem description. You need to _read_ the Tour that SO just sent you on when you registered, not ignore it.

Comment: I have one more question. In the program the choice of normal mode works fine but when I enter 2 (hard) it still says "normal mode chosen" and choses the normal mode. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that works is here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int number_normal;
int number_hard;
int guess_normal;
int guess_hard;
int tries_normal=0;
int tries_hard=0;
int mode;
int main()
{


    {
        cout<<"Choose your mode..."<<endl;
        cout<<"Normal (Press 1) or Hard (Press 2)"<<endl;
        cin>>mode;
        if(mode=1)
            cout<<"Normal mode chosen."<<endl;
                goto normal;
                if(mode=2)
                cout<<"Hard mode chosen!"<<endl;
                goto hard;
                return 0;
    }
{

    hard:

        cout<<"I chose a random number in a range from 1 to 100, can you      guess it?"<<endl;
        srand(time(NULL));
        number_hard = rand()%100+1;

    while(guess_hard!=number_hard)
        {
        tries_hard++;
        cout<<"Enter your guess!(Try "<<tries_hard<<"): ";
        cin>>guess_hard;

        if(guess_hard==number_normal)
            cout<<"Respect! You guessed it in "<<tries_hard<<" tries!"<<endl;
        }
}
{

    normal:

        cout<<"I chose a random number from 1 to 100. I will give you some clues! Try to guess it."<<endl;
        srand(time(NULL));
        number_normal = rand()%100+1;

    while(guess_normal!=number_normal)
        {
        tries_normal++;
        cout<<"Enter your guess!(Try "<<tries_normal<<"): ";
        cin>>guess_normal;

        if(guess_normal==number_normal)
            cout<<"Congrats! You're lucky. (Won in "<<tries_normal<<" tries!)"<<endl;

        if(guess_normal<number_normal)
            cout<<"Too low."<<endl;
        else if(guess_normal>number_normal)
            cout<<"That's too much!"<<endl;

        //system("pause");
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Well, you didn't used braces across your while loops, and as @cowls suggested, there was a closing brace missing after main. Everything else was fine. Also you used a `=` for comparison between to variables, instead of `==`, `=` is a assignment operator, while `==` is used for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a close brace at the end `}` that will close your main method.

I would also pay attention to the comments against the question addressing the other issues in your code.

Note: this could not be seen from the screenshot, showing why that was a  bad format to post your code in.